# How to index a sequential file in java?

Tags: java, file, indexing, sequential

I have a file and an index:

for example:

(the file)
----Id number

```
03 alex
02 juancho
01 homer
```

----(index) Id (It means, I've to read the file by Id, ascendant way)

My question is the next one, how make an structure that index the file to read it according to the index? (or key, in this case i'd be the Id)

If you can, drop some example in java. Thank you.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve the position of your data within the file via a simple mod-operation:

- Define the amount of possible slots (e.g. 100)
- Define the size of your data (e.g. 40 Bytes)

The calculation would be: **(INDEX mod 100) * 40**

- Index 0 -> Data begins at byte 0
- Index 32 -> Data begins at byte 1280

You can then use the calculated offset to do a [seek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) within your file.

There are some disadvantages with this solution, though

- your file will probably take a lot of space, no matter how much data is actually stored
- beware of colisions!

  - Index 101 -> Data begins at byte 40 (which is the same as index 1!)

---

This example shows only the principle behind simple indexes! Look out for more advanced solutions ;-)